# Extra Argument In Call

Tags: swift

I am trying to initialize a class and I am getting this error and can't for the life of me figure it out.

```
class Document {
    var title:String
    var body = ""
    var length: Int {
        get {
            return body.characters.count
        }
    }

    init(title:String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

let document1 = Document(title: "The Day", body: "It was a day to remember.") //error here on body
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, you‘re telling the Document class to take a title only when creating a new Document instance.
If you want to also pass a body when initializing, change your initializer to:

```
init(title: String, body: String) {
    self.title = title
    self.body = body
}
```

**Extra credit:**

Say, you don’t always want to pass a body when initializing a new Document, add a default value to `body`:

```
init(title: String, body: String = "") {
    self.title = title
    self.body = body
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
let doc = Document(title: "Test Doc")
```

Comment: How would I be able to initialize this class if I make this call also? 
`let document1 = Document(title: "Hello World")`